# Matlab: regular expression replace

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string, let's say it's "min(Current_em)", and I want to replace it with "Current_em" (ie the string inside the parentheses).

Looking at regular expression tutorials, I thought I wanted something like

```
regexprep('min(Current_em)', '.*\($0)', '$0')
```

But that doesn't do anything. Could I have some pointers into the dark art of regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match `(...)` and capture its contents with `'\(([^)]*)\)'` or `'\(([^()]*)\)'` (if inside, no `(` and `)` can appear).

Then, you need to replace with the backreference to the capturing group #1:

```
regexprep('min(Current_em)', '.*\(([^()]*)\)', '$1')
```

Pattern details:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, greedily, as many as possible (perhaps, you may replace it with `[^(]*` for better performance)
- `\(` - a literal `(` (must be escaped since it is a group open operator in regex)
- `([^()]*)`  - Capturing group #1 matching zero or more (`*`) chars other than (as `[^...]` is a *negated character class*) `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)` (must be escaped since it is a group close operator in regex)

Comment: that produces "minCurrent_em", I only want "Current_em". So I need `regexprep('min(Current_em)', '.*\(([^()]*)\)', '$1')`